# Disable CSS transitions on SLOW compouter

Tags: css, transition, lag

I have an expensive CSS transition on my website (I created a cloud, which becomes more transparent if you scroll down from the top). On older computers, my whole page starts lagging (scrolling also lags), so is there any solution for these?
- Make the transition less smooth, but leave CPU for scrolling, etc
- or detect older/slower computers, and disable the whole transition.

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]
Transition time: 10 sec.

[Github](https://github.com/DaWe35/CSS-clouds)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
    $("#cloud-back").css('box-shadow', '100vw 110vh 30px 0px #fff')
  } else {
    $("#cloud-back").css('box-shadow', '100vw 110vh 200px -100px #fff')
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --action: rgb(40, 51, 99);
  --gradient: linear-gradient(145deg, rgb(40, 51, 99), #13cadd);
  --shadow: 0 0 3rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  --background: #FFF;
  --grayWhite: #f5f5f5;
  --block-text: #FFF;
  --gradientLight: #13cadd;
  --gradientDark: rgb(40, 51, 99);
  --lightBlue: #8cc9e6;
  --sky: rgb(9, 33, 70);
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #f4623a;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #28a745;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #17a2b8;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #6c757d;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;
  --primary: #f4623a;
  --secondary: #6c757d;
  --success: #28a745;
  --info: #17a2b8;
  --warning: #ffc107;
  --danger: #dc3545;
  --light: #f8f9fa;
  --dark: #343a40;
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-color: var(--sky);
}

header,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: var(--background);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2,
h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

svg {
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button:not(:disabled),
[type="button"]:not(:disabled),
[type="reset"]:not(:disabled),
[type="submit"]:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  font: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

h2,
h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-8 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
  }
}

.was-validated .custom-control-input:valid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-input.is-valid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: #28a745;
}

.was-validated .custom-control-input:invalid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-input.is-invalid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: #dc3545;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee3e0d;
  border-color: #e23a0d;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(246, 122, 88, 0.5);
}

.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #545b62;
  border-color: #4e555b;
}

.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(130, 138, 145, 0.5);
}

.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1e7e34;
  border-color: #1c7430;
}

.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(72, 180, 97, 0.5);
}

.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #117a8b;
  border-color: #10707f;
}

.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(58, 176, 195, 0.5);
}

.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #d39e00;
  border-color: #c69500;
}

.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(222, 170, 12, 0.5);
}

.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bd2130;
  border-color: #b21f2d;
}

.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(225, 83, 97, 0.5);
}

.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #dae0e5;
  border-color: #d3d9df;
}

.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(216, 217, 219, 0.5);
}

.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1d2124;
  border-color: #171a1d;
}

.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(82, 88, 93, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f4623a;
  border-color: #f4623a;
}

.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(244, 98, 58, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6c757d;
  border-color: #6c757d;
}

.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
}

.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
  border-color: #17a2b8;
}

.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  border-color: #ffc107;
}

.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #dc3545;
  border-color: #dc3545;
}

.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(248, 249, 250, 0.5);
}

.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #343a40;
  border-color: #343a40;
}

.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5);
}

.custom-control-input:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: #fbc2b3;
}

.custom-control-input:not(:disabled):active~.custom-control-label::before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fde9e3;
  border-color: #fde9e3;
}

.close:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):hover,
.close:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):focus {
  opacity: .75;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center !important;
}

.align-items-center {
  align-items: center !important;
}

@supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {}

.m-5 {
  margin: 3rem !important;
}

.p-5 {
  padding: 3rem !important;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.text-white {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.text-muted {
  color: #6c757d !important;
}

@media print {
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    text-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  p,
  h2 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }
  h2 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  @page {
    size: a3;
  }
  body {
    min-width: 992px !important;
  }
  .container {
    min-width: 992px !important;
  }
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.page-section {
  padding: 8rem 0;
}

.two-blocks {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: var(--block-text);
  background-color: #0039e4;
  background: var(--gradient);
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear, filter .6s linear;
}

.two-blocks:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 140vh;
  background: var(--sky);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cloud {
  width: 110vw;
  height: 130vh;
  border-radius: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -130vh;
  left: -105vw;
}

#cloud-back {
  filter: url(#filter-back);
  transition: box-shadow 10s;
}

.minh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="DaWe">
  <title>CSS clouds</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100i,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
  <header class="minh-100" id="main">
    <!--   Cloud div -->
    <div class="bg-img">
      <div class="cloud" id="cloud-back" style="box-shadow: 100vw 110vh 30px 0px #fff"></div>
      <svg width="0" height="0"> 
    <filter id="filter-back">
    <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.012" numOctaves="4" seed="0" />
    <feDisplacementMap  in="SourceGraphic" scale="170" />
    </filter>
   </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center text-center minh-100">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 two-blocks">
        <h2>Scroll down</h2>
        <h4>100px</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 two-blocks">
        <h2>Scroll down</h2>
        <h4>100px</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <section class="page-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
          <h2 class="m-5 p-5 text-white">Hmmm</h2>
          <p class="text-muted m-5 p-5">When you scroll up, foggy cloud comes back ;)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are the older / slower computers running contemporary operating systems and / or browsers?

Comment: Yes, Win10 Chrome/Firefox. I'll test more.

Comment: What you really need is the `@media (update: slow)` query, but it apparently isn't supported in any browser. Maybe experiment with detecting `window.navigator.deviceMemory` and/or `window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency`? Wouldn't be perfect, but might be better than nothing.

Comment: That's cool, feel to free to post as an answer :)